# How to remove y axis of a figure with a discontinous x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a figure (as shown below) with discontinous x axis with the help of brokenaxes module.
https://pypi.org/project/brokenaxes/

[image]

But I don't know how to remove y axis in the figure. I tried some approaches from other quesitons, but seems not compatible with brokenaxes module. Anybody can help?

The code is presented here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))

bax = brokenaxes(xlims=((2500, 4000), (600, 1800)), hspace=1000)

p1= pd.read_csv("p1_1.csv", header=None,  skiprows=2)
p1=p1.values
p1=p1.transpose()
bax.plot(p1[0], p1[1])
bax.get_xaxis   
bax.invert_xaxis()

bax.set_xlabel('Wavenumber ($cm^{-1}$)')

bax.text(0.05, 0.3, "s", fontsize=12)

fig.savefig("1.png", bbox_inches = "tight")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please show the code that you've used to generate this figure

Comment: Hi, Diziet, noted, code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the individual sub-axes create by brokenaxes through the array `BrokenAxes.axs[]`

for some reason I had to turn the axis invisible and remove the spine as well, but this works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,3))

bax = brokenaxes(xlims=((2500, 4000), (600, 1800)), hspace=1000)

#p1= pd.read_csv("p1_1.csv", header=None,  skiprows=2)
#p1=p1.values
#p1=p1.transpose()
#bax.plot(p1[0], p1[1])
bax.invert_xaxis()

bax.set_xlabel('Wavenumber ($cm^{-1}$)')
bax.text(0.05, 0.3, "s", fontsize=12)

bax.axs[0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
bax.axs[0].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `axs` propertie of `bax`:

```
bax.axs[0].yaxis.set_visible(False)
bax.axs[0].spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```